# Windows 7 - Dual Monitors - Dual users logged in?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, multiple-users

I have a machine with 2 different user accounts. I also have dual monitors. Is there any application (free) out there that will let me be logged into both user accounts, one for each monitor...

Or, even better... an application that I can launch from my one logged in user that will open a desktop environment for my other account? Does any of this make sense? Sort of like a remote desktop window to my other account on the SAME machine in the same Windows 7 install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Windows 7 won't allow you to do this. But... **[Windows MultiPoint Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/)** will. It allows connecting multiple monitors, multiple keyboards, multiple mouses thru USB HUB's to work on one machine by multiple people. I've seen this in action and set it up couple of times so it's really nice. Mostly for students, classrooms with one big server and multiple mouses/keyboards/monitors.

> With Windows MultiPoint Server, a single computer supports multiple users at the same time, each working independently using their own monitor, keyboard and mouse and with a familiar Windows computing experience. Schools can provide more students with access to the latest technology, even with limited budgets.

Comment: +1 Nice find, I didn't know about that program. Though @myermian, you could also potentially go the other route and get another computer, either using RDP to actually _have_ an RDP session to another user, or you could hook up monitor #2 (or #3) to it and use something like Synergy. (http://synergy-foss.org/)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, there is a patch that you can apply to Windows 7 to remove the multiple login restriction.

> 1. Download this [Concurrent sessions enabler.zip](http://www.missingremote.com/images/stories/Win7RDP/Concurrent_RDP_Win7_Beta_7000.zip)
> 2. Extract the files from above downloaded zip file
> 3. **Shift+ Right Click on install.cmd** file and select run as administrator.
> 4. That’s it. You should see below screen after you have executed install.cmd

[image]

Source: http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm

Comment: Above "Concurrent sessions enabler.zip" link is broken. Anyone came across another working link ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Windows client only allows a single interactive logon at a time.  If it was server this might be possible logon to the console with one account, them open a RDP session with the other account on one screen